# Enable DEVPTS_FS option in Linux kernel 2.6.26.5

Tags: kernel, make, busybox, virtual-file-system

Board with embedded Linux kernel version 2.6.26.5, for ARM target. Busybox 1.10.2. How to enable `DEVPTS` virtual filesystem support in kernel? I tried to find item `CONFIG_DEVPTS_FS` in config files, but didn't find it. There are several config files located in directories in recursive order, the /linux-2.6.26.5/.config have items

```
CONFIG_UNIX98_PTYS=y
CONFIG_LEGACY_PTYS=y
```

but not the `DEVPTS_FS` option.

Nevertheless, Busybox .config file have entry `# CONFIG_FEATURE_DEVPTS is not set`. The source package have 'devpts' folder in /linux-2.6.26.5/fs/ containing devpts.o, makefile for the Linux /dev/pts virtual filesystem, also 'devpts_fs.h' in /linux-2.6.26.5/include/linux/ folder.
So, does this mean the kernel have no support for DEVPTS_FS option, or it can be set?

Comment: It might be already here. I hope you have /proc support. try cat /proc/filesystems on the device. If you see devpts it's definitively here. If not, I wouldn't know (was it available as module then?). The option hasn't always existed and doesn't exist today.

Comment: The /proc support is enabled, but I can't check actual filesystems from CLI before building a full source package, as an existing build have no full shell access. Should I enable `FEATURE_DEVPTS` in Busybox .config file, its not clear why it's placed there?

Comment: If you want the feature of course.

Comment: Not clear one point: the DEVPTS filesystem is Linux kernel feature, why this option is included in the Busybox config?